# Dúvida - Update em SQL a partir de formulário PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, id

Tenho uma tabela em que as colunas 1 a 5 são dados fixos que eu alimento o SQL e ela aparece a listagem na página WEB.
Nesta página WEB tenho um formulário em que o usuário deverá responder 3 perguntas, em inputs nas colunas de 6 a 8.

Acontece que a planilha está atualizando todas as linhas com o dado respondido na última linha. como faço para corrigir?

Minha função update:

```
function insereDado($conexao, $id, $campo6, $campo7, $campo8) {
$query = "update dbo.avalia_pf2 set campo6 = '{$campo6}', campo7 = '{$campo7}', campo8 = '{$campo8}' where id= {$id}";
$resultadoDaInsercao = mssql_query($query, $conexao);
return $resultadoDaInsercao;
```

Minhas variáveis:

```
$id = 'id';
$campo6 = $_POST["campo6"];
$campo7 = $_POST["campo7"];
$campo8 = $_POST["campo8"];
```

Meu form:

```
<form action="adiciona-dado.php" method="post">
                <table class="table table-striped">         
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titulo_cell">Título 1</th>
                            <th class="titulo_cell" >Título 2</th>
                            <th class="titulo_cell" >Título 3</th>
                            <th class="titulo_cell" >Título 4</th>
                            <th class="titulo_cell" >Título 5</th>
                            <th class="titulo_cell" >Pergunta 1</th>
                            <th class="titulo_cell" >Pergunta 2</th>
                            <th class="titulo_cell" >Pergunta 3</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <?php $dados = listaDados($conexao); foreach($dados as $dado) : ?>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td name="campo1"> <?php echo $dado['Campo1']; ?> </td>
                                <td name="campo2"> <?php echo $dado['Campo2']; ?> </td>
                                <td name="campo3"> <?php echo $dado['Campo3']; ?> </td>
                                <td name="campo4"> <?php echo $dado['Campo4']; ?></td>
                                <td name="campo5"> <?php echo $dado['Campo5']; ?> </td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="campo6" class="form-control"><? $dado['Campo6']?></input></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="campo7" class="form-control"><? $dado['Campo7']?></input></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="campo8" class="form-control"><? $dado['Campo8']?></input></td>
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn">Incluir</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Informação importante: meu ID é "NOT NULL" (não é primary key com auto incremento)
Como faço para corrigir o UPDATE? É alguma informação que passo na hora de declarar a variável $id mas não estou conseguindo chegar no resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, vamos pelo básico,
Quando você chama função insedeDados você está passando o ID?
se sim, da um var_dumb($id) dentro da sua função e vê se ele retorna o número do id, talvez a função não esteja recebendo o id e por isso ta dando problema.

Comment: Não consegui entender, onde eu insiro o var_dumb($id)

Comment: `function insereDado($conexao, $id, $campo6, $campo7, $campo8) {
var_dump($id);
$query = "update dbo.avalia_pf2 set campo6 = '{$campo6}', campo7 = '{$campo7}', campo8 = '{$campo8}' where id= {$id}";
$resultadoDaInsercao = mssql_query($query, $conexao);
return $resultadoDaInsercao;`

Comment: Não funcionou ainda.

Comment: Como você faz pra atribuir o valor da variável $id e posteriormente enviar  pra função?

Comment: $id = 'id';
Eu também tentei com $id = $_POST["id"];  e com $id = $_GET["id"];

Comment: Quando você da um enviar no seu formulário, ele vai pegar todas aquelas informações e enviar para a página  adiciona-dado.php, certo? 
pois bem, nesta página imagino que você tenha: `

Comment: Quando você da um enviar no seu formulário, ele vai pegar todas aquelas informações e enviar para a página  adiciona-dado.php, certo? 
pois bem, nesta página imagino que você tenha: `
$campo6 = $_POST["campo6"];
..

Você precisar ter algo que referencie o ID pode ser $id = 4 se você quer passar manualmente o valor do id para a variável, ou $id = $_POST['id'] se está vindo do lá seu formulário. Pelo que vi no seu código você não esta atribuindo valor pra variável id no adiciona-dado.php e por isso está com problemas.
Qualquer coisa me manda um inbox que eu te ajudo.

Comment: Oi... então, o ID não vem do formulário, eu importo uma planilha para o SQL, as colunas 6, 7 e 8 têm inputs para responderem por formulário..

Answer (score 0):

1) Você precisa criar um campo `hidden` com o valor do seu id no formuário, como em `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id_do_registro?>">`

2) Recuperar este id na página seguinte por `$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);`

Perceba que usei a função `filter_input` para recuperar o valor. Você deveria utilizar este filtro sempre que recuperar variáveis enviadas pelo usuário, por segurança. Leia mais em http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: Rafael, mas, no caso o ID não é enviado pelo usuário... eu que informo o número do ID quando envio a planilha para o SQL.

Comment: Por isso sugeri o campo `hidden`, que é para estar preenchido com o valor que você conhece. No exemplo que você enviou ID está permanentemente com o valor de string `'id'` e, com isso, sua consulta acaba atualizando todos os registros do banco de dados, pois a sua cláusula WHERE será transformada em `WHERE id = id`, o que é sempre verdadeiro. É necessário que você preencha previamente o campo `hidden` com o valor de ID que vem do banco e dados e o recupere na página seguinte com o valor correspondente. E assim sua variável ID terá o valor correto.

Comment: Você pode abrir a página do formulário passando o id por query string `form.php?id=321` e, no campo hidden, usar este valor, como em `$id_do_registro = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);` e apresentando no html como `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id_do_registro?>">`